# PHP 5.3 and 5.4 produces warning with exif_read_data()

Tags: php, exif

I have a little problem with PHP's exif_read_data().

The Script works fine on my local xampp. But it produces warnings once I upload it to the server
The Warning i get is:

```
Warning: exif_read_data(_kkk8242.jpg): File not supported in ......../helper.php on line 74
```

[It happens with all my files.](http://kiess.uhostfull.com/images/stories/flexicontent/item_21_field_15/original/_kkk8242.jpg)

[The file itself contains exif data](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fkiess.uhostfull.com%2Fimages%2Fstories%2Fflexicontent%2Fitem_21_field_15%2Foriginal%2F_kkk8242.jpg)

Im running PHP 5.4 (also tried 5.3) on my server. What could be the problem?

phpinfo() gives the same data for both environments:

- EXIF Support enabled
- EXIF Version 1.4 $Id$
- Supported EXIF Version 0220
- Supported filetypes  JPEG,TIFF

Any ideas on why exif_read_data() fails on my server?

thanks in advance

(if i forgot to add any relevant information let me say im sorry :D )

Comment: No idea what your script does or how it works.  But that ......../ looks dodgy.

Comment: that ".............." is just the folder structure i removed. the script does basically just go through a selected category of pictures and reads out their exif and returns them as a json object.